# Aggs percentage doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch

So I know my total hits are 182 documents

```
"hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 182,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
```

And then I make a aggregation to know how many documents have the source instagagram or twitter and it returns me:

```
"bySource": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "instagram",
                    "doc_count": 162
                },
                {
                    "key": "twitter",
                    "doc_count": 20
                }
            ]
        }
```

Is it possible to get the percentage of documents that have source twitter and instagram?
So the percentage of documents that have source instagram is 89 % and twitter 11%.

My aggregation code its like this:

```
"aggs": {
        "bySource": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "profile.source.keyword"
            }
        }
}
```

Let me know if this is possible.
Thank you

Comment: Try use [Bucker script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html). Your mapping has any field date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is possible using the '[Bucket Script Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation)'.

An example query might look like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "filters_agg": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": {
                    "sourceCount": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "bySource": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "profile.source.keyword"
                    }
                },
                "instagram_count_percentage": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "instagram_count": "bySource['instagram']>_count",
                            "total_count": "_count"
                        },
                        "script": "Math.round((params.instagram_count * 100)/params.total_count)"
                    }
                },
                "twitter_count_percentage": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "twitter_count": "bySource['twitter']>_count",
                            "total_count": "_count"
                        },
                        "script": "Math.round((params.twitter_count * 100)/params.total_count)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the response could be something like this:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 182,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "filters_agg": {
      "buckets": {
        "sourceCount": {
          "doc_count": 182,
          "bySource": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "instagram",
                "doc_count": 162
              },
              {
                "key": "twitter",
                "doc_count": 20
              }
            ]
          },
          "instagram_count_percentage": {
            "value": 89
          },
          "twitter_count_percentage": {
            "value": 11
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try to adjust it or get inspired depending on your case and your mapping.